# Difference between the two url specified

Tags: javascript

A simple question ,what is the difference between the two URL specified

/learn-management/lesson/:lessonID? vs /learn-management/lesson/:lessonID

what does the '?' after lessonID mean ?

ExpressJS is being used for backend api.

Comment: `?` is the separator between the resource path and the query params - example - https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/Structure_of_an_HTTP_style_URI_or_URL.png

with that said, there is no problem to leave it with the `?` or without it

Comment: @ericmp thanks even i felt so,but was not sure